# In list how to count string in a sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a list with duplicate elements. I want to count the occurrence of each element

example->
    `list1= ["a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "d", "a", "a"]`

output->
`result = ["a1", "b2", "c1", "d3", "a2"]`

i.e. output format should be `<value><count>`

I have tried this solution, but its not giving expected output

```
def find_repetitive_elem(a):
    dict_obj = {}
    arr_obj = []
    for i in range(0, len(a)-1):
        count = 1    
        if a[i] == a[i+1]
            set_val = "%s%s" % (a[i], count+1)
        else:
            set_val = "%s%s" % (a[i], count)                
        arr_obj.append(set_val)
```

I'm trying to implement this using algorithm and not by python package's!

Comment: So? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Take a look at the `collections.Counter` type.

Comment: I'm interested - will `collections.Counter` work in these circumstances, ie where the letters have to be consecutive?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

list1= ["a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "d", "a", "a"]

answer = [group[0] + str(len(list(group[1]))) for group in groupby(list1)]
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
['a1', 'b2', 'c1', 'd3', 'a2']
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but i'm looking for actual algorithm to find the output.

Comment: Be sure to edit your question to state that you want the actual algorithm!

Comment: added that.. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` from the `itertools` module to achieve this:

```
import itertools
list1= ["a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "d", "a", "a"]
["{}{}".format(key,sum( 1 for _ in group )) for key, group in itertools.groupby( list1 ) ]
```

As you have updated your answer stating that you do not want to use a Python package, this is the most elegant way I could think off that doesn't use external modules:

```
list1= ["a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "d", "a", "a"]

#output-> result = ["a1", "b2", "c1", "d3", "a2"]

def find_repetitive_elem(array):
    output=[]           
    for letter in array:
        existing_entry = {}
        new_entry = {}
        if len(output)>0:            
            existing_entry= output.pop();            
        if letter in existing_entry:            
            existing_entry[letter] +=1            
            output.append(existing_entry)
        else:            
            if existing_entry:            
                output.append(existing_entry)
            new_entry[letter]=1
            output.append(new_entry)                        

    return output

output = find_repetitive_elem(list1)        
print ["{}{}".format(key,value) for key,value in (entry.popitem() for entry in output)]
```

Comment: I have added a second solution that doesn't require external Python modules

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by

> I'm trying to implement this using algorithm and not by python
>   package's!

This is without using itertools (though that is a far better way to do this)

```
def compact(inval):
    last_char = None
    outval = []
    count = 0
    for l in inval + ['dummyvalue']:
        if last_char and last_char != l:
            outval.append("{}{}".format(last_char, count))
            count = 0
        last_char = l
        count += 1
    return outval

letters = ["a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "d", "a", "a"]
print(compact(letters))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
letters = ["a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "d", "a", "a"] # yields
['a1', 'b2', 'c1', 'd3', 'a2']

letters = ["a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "d", "d", "d", "a", "a"] # yields
['a1', 'b2', 'c2', 'd1', 'e1', 'd3', 'a2']
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you do not want to use any of Python's modules, here is a solution that does not use any (except for `builtins` implicitly). The code should be able to work on more than just strings.

```
def main():
    array = 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'a', 'a'
    result = find_repetitive_elements(array)
    print(result)


def find_repetitive_elements(array):
    result, first, last, count = [], True, None, None
    for item in array:
        if first:
            first, last, count = False, item, 1
        elif item == last:
            count += 1
        else:
            result.append('{}{}'.format(last, count))
            last, count = item, 1
    if not first:
        result.append('{}{}'.format(last, count))
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

This might look very basic, but this is how I understood the question:

**Code:**

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "d", "a", "a"]

def find_repetitive_elem_continuously(arr):
    result = list()
    prev_ele = arr[0]
    count = 0
    for curr_ele in arr:
        if curr_ele != prev_ele:
            new_arr_ele = str(prev_ele)+""+str(count)
            result.append(new_arr_ele)
            prev_ele = curr_ele
            count = 1
        else:
            count += 1
    new_arr_ele = str(prev_ele)+""+str(count)
    result.append(new_arr_ele)
    print result

find_repetitive_elem_continuously(list1)
```

**Output:**

```
['a1', 'b2', 'c1', 'd3', 'a2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt without using `itertools.groupby`. The code relies on `itertools.dropwhile` iterator, but it is quite easy to replace it and I leave this as an exercise for you.

```
import itertools

list1= ["a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "d", "a", "a"]

result = []
lst = list1.copy()

while len(lst)>0:
    current_char = lst[0]
    length = len(lst)
    lst = list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x==current_char, lst))
    result.append("{}{}".format(current_char, length-len(lst)))

print(result)
```

See code output at http://ideone.com/Cd1Y8B